# How to determine tag, index and offset size in a two-way associative cache

Tags: cache

How to determine tag, index and offset size in a two-way associative cache with a 1MB two-way set associative cache with 8 byte blocks

Comment: What have you tried until now? How did you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume a 32 Bit address.

The offset is trivially $log(8)=3$ as it basically indexes the amount of bytes in each block.

The Index is a bit more difficult:

$\frac{1MB}{8B} = 128K$

$\frac{128K}{2} = 64K$

$log(64k) = 16$

We calculate the total amount of blocks, then the amount of blocks per cache set and then get the log of that.

The Tag is just the remaining bits in the address: $32-16-3=13$ Bits.

So the address looks like this: [Tag: 13 Bits][Index: 16 Bits][Offset: 3 Bits]

Comment: isnt (1mb/8b) = 125000 not 128000?

Comment: No. $\frac{1024^3}{8} = 1024^2 * 128 $

Comment: @natalia Did this answer your gestion? If so could you accept the answer?

Comment: thank you so much!